# Declaring projection in Loader in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I took up for learning kotlin so I decided to write a simply app using RecyclerView in conduction with database with content providers.
Currently I stuck in MainActivity in `onCreateLoader` method.
In java I used to declare projection this way:

```
String[] projection  = {
        WalletEntry._ID,
        WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE,
        WalletEntry.KEY_MONEY,
        WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_DATE,
        WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_EXPENSE,
        WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_TRANSACTION_TITLE
    };
```

that worked fine. But in kotlin when I try to define projection in similar way I get an error while returning this:

```
val projection  = arrayOf({
            WalletEntry._ID
            WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE
            WalletEntry.KEY_MONEY
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_DATE
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_EXPENSE
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_TRANSACTION_TITLE
        })

        return applicationContext?.let { context ->
            CursorLoader(context,
                    WalletEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null)
        }!!
```

It gives me an error saying: Type mismatch
required: Array<(out) String!>?
found: Array<() -> String>
and to be honest I have no idea how to fix it. I saw in some sources code that people simply use name of the table instead of calling Contract class and its entry, but I find it a little bit messy when changing tables' name.

BTW, there is no comas between table names, AS finds it as an unexpected token

So, how can I reformat my projection to fix the error?

Comment: change `arrayOf({...})` to `arrayOf(...)`.

Comment: *there is no comas between table names*, there should be.

Answer (score 0):

When you enclose the list of fields into {} kotlin interprets it as a "function" body, the return value would be the last line, so the type kotlin founds is:

```
Array<() -> String> // An array of functions with no parameters that returns strings
```

So when you create the array, you are creating an array of "functions" when the required type by the CursorLoader is

```
Array<(out) String!>? //A nullable array of strings
```

As @rciovati told you, just delete the {} and you will have the right type for CursorLoader ()